# Excel Templates on Mac OS 10.15

Tags: ms-office

Where are my Excel templates located on Mac OS 10.15?

I know its a hidden folder and once in the right location you hold down a certain key, such as the Option or Command key, and the folder appears.

Comment: Does this help? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-for-mac-2019-templates/8462975f-0cfc-4341-b868-a02c685d0e7e

Comment: Yes, but I had found the answer earlier today. Go to the finder and then click on the Go dropdown from the menu bar, then click and fold the Option key. A hidden library appears and you sift through there to Microsoft and the templates can be found. Thank You!